# Almacenar datos en una vsariable y reutilizarla en google maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

quisiera poder almacenar datos de una consulta htpp, estos datos son latitudes y longitudes que luego tengo que cargar en un mapa, el problema es que actualmente estos datos me los carga cuando abro el mapa y tarda mucho en mostrarlos, quisiera poder dejarlos almacenados en una variable al iniciar la app para que el tiempo de carga sea mas rapido al reutilizarla y no tenga que estar haciendo la consulta http cuando inicia el mapa.

ESTE ES EL MAIN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACA SE CREA EL MAPA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACA OBTENGO LOS DATOS DE LOS COMERCIOS DESDE UN WEBSERVICE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AQUI SETEO LAS LATITUDES Y LONGITUDES QUE ME TRAE EL WEB SERVICE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask]. Por favor agrega el código como texto para que sea más facil ayudarte a depurar. Saludos

Comment: Tienes varias opciones. Una de ellas es guardar la latitud y longitud en el local storage del dispositivo usando [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) y luego recuperandolas en la pantalla que necesitas. Otra opción es usando una clase session en la cual guardes los datos. Para esta opción te recomiendo usar singleton pero también puedes crear un Service e inyectarlo con el ChangeNotifierProvider y recuperarlo cuando lo necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!